# Add key in Array of object if match condition

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get an array of objects based on a condition. If the value is true then only add that key and value to new array of object.

But, It gives error:

```js
const arr = [{id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd'}, {id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd', show: true}, {id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd', show: false}, {id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd'}]

const newArr = arr.map(item => ({id: item.id, val: item.val != null ? item.val : ''}))

console.log(newArr); //It is working
```

```js
const arr = [{id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd'}, {id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd', show: true}, {id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd', show: false}, {id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd'}]

const expectedArr = arr.map(item => ({id: item.id, val: item.val != null ? item.val : '', (item.show) && (show: item.show)}))

console.log(expectedArr); //Shows error
```

Expected Result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "val": "abcd"
  },
  {
    "id": 123,
    "val": "abcd"
    "show": true
  },
  {
    "id": 123,
    "val": "abcd"
  },
  {
    "id": 123,
    "val": "abcd"
  }
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: (show) && (show: val.show)}) should be (item.show) && (show: item.show)})?

Comment: @lissettdm Sorry, typo

Comment: Change `(item.show) && (show: item.show)` to `...(item.show && {show: item.show})`

Comment: @Yousaf No that one also not working

Comment: [Working Demo](https://jsbin.com/padigevuki/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: this dude just code golfed something that is extremely easy with using proper syntax.. but hey i bored so im halfway thru solving it rn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that ?

```js
const arr = 
      [ { id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd' } 
      , { id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd', show: true  } 
      , { id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd', show: false } 
      , { id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd' } 
      ] 

const newArr = arr.map(({id,val,show})=>show?{id,val,show}:{id,val})

console.log( newArr )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite it like this.
with this syntax you, when `item.show` is true the parenthesis resolve to and object and then you just spread it into your object.
You can also use nullish coalescing to assign `item.val`

```
 const expectedArr = arr.map((item) => ({
      id: item.id,
      val: item.val ?? "",
      ...(item.show && { show: item.show }),
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it contains multiple conditions on one line inside `Array.map` function and it's not valid.

```js
const arr = [{id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd'}, {id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd', show: true}, {id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd', show: false}, {id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd'}]

const result = arr.map(({ id, val, show }) => {
  const newObj = {
    id,
    val: val != null ? val : ''
  };
  if (show) {
    newObj['show'] = show;
  }
  return newObj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [{id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd'}, {id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd', show: true}, {id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd', show: false}, {id: 123, val: 'abcd', other: 'abcd'}]

const expectedArr = arr.map(item => ({id: item.id, val: item.val? item.val: '', show: item.show? item.show: 0}))

console.log(expectedArr); //solved-ish

//but honestly, that's the furthest i can go with your strange code golfed syntax setup.. to be honest, using ? is similar to if but NOT if, it's closer to || but anyway

console.log('skip what was above, the moment of truth below')

const theRealAnswer = arr.map(item=>{ const i={id: item.id, val: item.val? item.val: '', show: item.show? item.show: 0};if(!i.show){delete(i.show)}return(i) })

console.log(theRealAnswer)

//now, the logical construct(what u gave the mapper) was impossible to do what u wanted. coding isn't just syntax, it's logic too. you cannot assign a key to completely delete the key itself
```